# pass parameters as per url in routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to pass parameters from one action to another action.
my url routing is like below:

```
 routes.MapRoute("SearchDealbyPrice", "Deal/CategoriesID/{CategoriesID}/FromPrice/{FromPrice}/ToPrice/{ToPrice}/Price/{Price}/GreenCars/{GreenCars}/PageName/{PageName}", defaults: new { controller = "Deal", action = "Index" });
```

I need to display URL like below:

```
Deal/CategoriesID/9/FromPrice/100/ToPrice/200/Price/0/GreenCars/0/PageName/Garrage
```

How can I achieve this from controller?
from controller I need to pass these parameters and URL should display like above.

Thanks
Lalitha

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for ?
I've added your route to RouteConfig and in DealController I've put a RedirectExample method :

```
public ActionResult RedirectExample() {
      return RedirectToRoute("SearchDealbyPrice", new {CategoriesID = 9,FromPrice = 100,ToPrice = 200,Price = 0,GreenCars = 0,PageName= "Garrage"}); }
```

It works fine. When I go to http://localhost:51639/Deal/RedirectExample then route redirects to the Index method in the Deal controller and the result URL is as follows http://localhost:51639/Deal/CategoriesID/9/FromPrice/100/ToPrice/200/Price/0/GreenCars/0/PageName/Garrage

Comment: Thanks. I have tried like below:  return RedirectPermanent("Deal/CategoriesID/" + categoryId + "/FromPrice/" + model.FromPrice + "/ToPrice/" + model.ToPrice + "/Price/" + model.IsBusinessPrice + "/GreenCars/" + isGreenCars + "/PageName/SpecialGarage");. It is also working

Comment: Hi Lukas, Sorry, I dont know how to accept the answer. could you please guide me?